# How to change armature pose with ragdoll?

Tags: rigging, rigid-body-simulation

I can’t figure out one thing that confuses me. Or I am misunderstanding something. Let’s say I made a rig, at least for a human model, at least for a worm. I can change the pose however I want, and all that jazz. However, as far as I know, in order to create a ragdoll, the bones must be detached from the parental bonds, i.e. be on your own. In this case, how to pose, raise arms, legs, etc., in a model that has a ragdoll?

https://youtu.be/KUmIKWVrHZU?t=108

After all, even in this video, the guy says that you need to remove all child-parent bonds in the bones, otherwise the bones just stick to each other and the ragdoll does not work.

And since every bone is now on its own, how can I change poses, spread my arms and legs, other than tedious dragging and dropping meshes for ragdoll?